# 2nd auto-nav block (globally) with different links using Concrete5

Tags: php, navigation, concrete5

I have a concrete5 site already using an autonav block in the global header for the main site navigation.

I now need to add a secondary navigation to the header containing different, less important links. 
These links aren't necessarily to be shown in sitemap order, but I would prefer to use an auto-nav block if possible to do so.

Can anyone give me any tips on how to achieve this?
Can I get there somehow using Aliases on the sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at using Bread Crumbs?  We also use Mega Menu..  There are quite a few menuing systems from concrete5.org.  Note: Mega Menu is not free, but is worth it..  The other thing is that sometimes the "File Tree" and "File Sets" may have to be re-ordered..  While in the file Tree, choose the option to update cache..

Comment: More looking to split the top navigation items into two distinct lists. More utilitarian pages like About / Contact etc to have less prominence than shop / support etc.

Thanks for the tip though - will check out the mega menu add-on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a page attribute. You could use a checkbox for instance, call it secondary and if checked make your secondary nav to show it.

Comment: How would this approach get around the order needing to be different to sitemap order?

Comment: It wouldn't. What it will do however is select what links to show or not show so you can have a different page list. In your question, it seems that was the main point, order was just a mention in passing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page list and an boolean attribute(for example: display_in_second_nav)
Here is an example:

```
$pl = new PageList();
$pl->filterByAttribute('display_in_second_nav');
$pages = $pl->get();
```

Also, you can sort results:

```
$pl->sortByRelevance()
```

Orders by index score descending. Only available when searching by keywords.

```
$pl->sortByDisplayOrder()
```

Orders by sitemap display order ascending.

```
$pl->sortByDisplayOrderDescending()
```

Orders by sitemap display order descending.

```
$pl->sortByPublicDate()
```

Orders by public date ascending.

```
$pl->sortByPublicDateDescending()
```

Orders by public date descending.

```
$pl->sortByName()
```

Orders by page name ascending.

```
$pl->sortByNameDescending()
```

Orders by name descending.